# Calculate daysAgo return wrong days

Tags: android

I'm trying to calculate daysAgo from two dates, the phone date time and my passed date.

this is my code:

```
int daysAgo = DateUtilities.getTimeAgo(DateUtilities.stringToDateTime(updatedAt, true).getTime());

public static int getTimeAgo(long time) {
            if (time < 1000000000000L) {
                time *= 1000;
            }

            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (time > now || time <= 0) {
                return 0;
            }

            final long diff = now - time;
            return (int) (diff / DAY_MILLIS);
        }

public static Date stringToDateTime(String dateTime, boolean useUtc) throws ParseException {
            if (useUtc) {
                return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(dateTime);
            } else {
                return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").parse(dateTime);
            }
        }
```

this code as `int daysAgo` return wrong days for me, i pass this date to calculate: `2017-11-18T20:31:04.000Z` and my phone date time as `System.currentTimeMillis()` is `1511080129979` and then result of returned `daysAgo` is `305`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use "MM" to represent the month, not the "mm". It is for minutes. Your code

```
return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(dateTime);
return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd").parse(dateTime);
```

should be changed to

```
return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(dateTime);
return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(dateTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem over here is pre-optimization.

```
int daysAgo = DateUtilities.getTimeAgo(DateUtilities.stringToDateTime(updatedAt, true).getTime());

return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(dateTime);
```

The above statements are perfect only when you know what they are doing, otherwise, they are impossible to even debug.

These are the situations where we understand the real importance of TDD.

### The TDD approach

**DateUtilitiesUnitTest**

```
public class DateUtilitiesUnitTest
{
    @Test
    public void testStringToDateTimeConversion()
    {
        Calendar expectedCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        // Here we set the month as Calendar.NOVEMBER
        // As per the Calendar API, month 11 == DECEMBER
        expectedCal.set(2017, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 18, 20, 31, 4);

        Date actualDate = DateUtilities.stringToDateTime("2017-11-18T20:31:04.000Z");
        Calendar actualCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        actualCal.setTime(actualDate);

        // Date.equals(Date), compares two Dates with the milliseconds precision, and cannot be used reliably
        // hence, we have to compare all the individual elements separately
        assertEquals("Year should be 2017", expectedCal.get(Calendar.YEAR), actualCal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        assertEquals("Month should be " + expectedCal.get(Calendar.MONTH), expectedCal.get(Calendar.MONTH), actualCal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        assertEquals("Day should be 18", expectedCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), actualCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        // If required, you may go ahead and compare Hours, Minutes and Seconds
    }

}
```

#### === Step 1 (Fail the Test) ===

**DateUtilities.java**

```
public static Date stringToDateTime(String dateTime)
{
    return null;
}
```

**Test Result**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

#### === Step 2 (Just enough to Pass the test) ===

**DateUtilities.java**

```
public static Date stringToDateTime(String dateTime)
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Here we set the month as Calendar.NOVEMBER
    // As per the Calendar API, month 11 == DECEMBER
    cal.set(2017, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 18, 20, 31, 4);

    return cal.getTime();
}
```

**Test Result**

```
1 Test passed
```

Failing and then Passing the "pseudo tests" proves that your Test is actually working and that you are in fact testing the correct method.

#### === Step 3 (Start Implementation) ===

**DateUtilities.java**

```
public static Date stringToDateTime(String dateTime)
{
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = format.parse(dateTime);
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return date;
}
```

**Test Result**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Month should be 10 
Expected :10
Actual   :0
```

We caught the issue!
Expected month is 10 (Calendar.NOVEMBER)
but, we got 0 (Calendar.JANUARY)

#### === Step 4 (Fix it!) ===

**DateUtilities.java**

```
public static Date stringToDateTime(String dateTime)
{
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = format.parse(dateTime);
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return date;
}
```

**Test Result**

```
1 Test passed
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the date format to

```
public static Date stringToDateTime(String dateTime, boolean useUtc) throws ParseException {
            if (useUtc) {
                return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(dateTime);
            } else {
                return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(dateTime);
            }
        }
```

In date `mm` denotes to `minutes` where `MM` denotes to `months`.